# Как сохранить файл base64 по ссылке Angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2, download

У меня есть список файлов(разные xlsx, txt итд) я хочу при клике на файл скачивать его, но вместо скачки файла у меня скачивается страница сайта, в чем моя ошибка я не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста.  Пробовал Blob но там и имена странные и мне просто в текстовом файле выгружает код base64

```js
onClickFileDownload(file, a) {
  const linkSource = `data:${file.type};base64,${file.content}`;
  this.linkSrc = linkSource;
  a.click();
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let file of attachedFiles">
  <div class="label" (click)="onClickFileDownload(file, download)">{{file.filename}}</div>
  <a download="{{file.filename}}" href="{{linkSrc}}" #download></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему так получалось понять не могу возможно было много причине того что возвращалась битая ссылка и она вроде как без типа в начале приходила сейчас работает вот так

```js
func(result) {
  const linkSource = result.content;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  const fileName = result.filename;

  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
}
```